# Using JSON in C# deserialized into a dictionary

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I deserialized JSON data into a dictionary. This is what my JSON data looks like:

```
{
    "InputKoffRetStats":true,"InputPenaltyStats":false,
    "VisitingTeamFootballRbStats":
         [{
             "AthleteLastName":"John",
             "AthleteFirstName":"Smith","Number":9,"IsPresent":true
         },
         {
             "AthleteLastName":"Justin",
             "AthleteFirstName":"Brooks","Number":10,"IsPresent":false
         }]
}
```

And this is how I deserialized the string into a dictionary:

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(result);
```

The problem I have is that I do not know how to get, for example, the first athlete's last name (John).

If I do this:

```
 Console.WriteLine(dict["InputKoffRetStats"]);
```

Then I get "True". It works fine.

If I do this:

```
Console.WriteLine(dict["VisitingTeamFootballRbStats"]);
```

Then I get the information of both athletes (John and Justin).

How could I use the dictionary to get only the first athletes name? I tried doing the following with no success:

```
Console.WriteLine(dict["VisitingTeamFootballRbStats"][0]);
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: I should have mentionned that the json that I showed is just a small portion of the whole json. I just gave it as an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A full working example:

```
public class Athlete
{
    public string AthleteLastName { get; set; }
    public string AthleteFirstName { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public bool IsPresent { get; set; }
}

public class Stat
{
    public bool InputKoffRetStats { get; set; }
    public bool InputPenaltyStats { get; set; }
    public List<Athlete> VisitingTeamFootballRbStats { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var jsonText = "{" +
                        "    \"InputKoffRetStats\":true,\"InputPenaltyStats\":false," +
                        "    \"VisitingTeamFootballRbStats\":" +
                        "         [{" +
                        "             \"AthleteLastName\":\"John\"," +
                        "             \"AthleteFirstName\":\"Smith\",\"Number\":9,\"IsPresent\":true" +
                        "         }," +
                        "         {" +
                        "             \"AthleteLastName\":\"Justin\"," +
                        "             \"AthleteFirstName\":\"Brooks\",\"Number\":10,\"IsPresent\":false" +
                        "         }]" +
                        "}";

        var stat = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Stat>(jsonText);

        Console.WriteLine(stat.VisitingTeamFootballRbStats[0].AthleteFirstName);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

PS.: There was an error in the JSON you provided. Once you're using `"IsPresent"` as a boolean: `"IsPresent":true`, the next time you're using it as a string: `"IsPresent":No` (Incorrectly, because No should be "No"). Anyway, I corrected that to be `"IsPresent":false`.

**Update**: If you want "JavaScript-like" behavior, so you want to be able to do `someObj["someProperty"]["someNestedProperty"]` you can do this:

```
var stat = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonText);
```

So to get to the first name of the first athlete:

```
var firstName = stat["VisitingTeamFootballRbStats"][0]["AthleteFirstName"].Value<string>();
```

That said, I would still create proper classes for all the possible fields in the JSON.

Comment: This is very cool. However, the jsonText I gave was just a short part of the whole text. The whole json is over 1000 lines long. Your classes work fine in the example, but won't work with the whole text. Is there any way to create a generic class ?

Comment: You mean the `VisitingTeamFootballRbStats` array gets pretty long or there are other fields in the outer { ... } in the JSON. If the JSON is known and not going to change, I would still go with adding proper classes to my .NET project and deserialize into that. Btw, the above is just an example, I wouldn't put a 1000 lines into a variable, I assume you read it from a file or get it over the internet. :)

Comment: Yeah, I mean that there are other fields in the JSON. I take it from a file.

Answer (score 1):

The other way to deserialize is to create a JsonProperty class like below:

```
public class VisitingTeamFootballRbStats
{
    [JsonProperty("AthleteLastName")]
    public string AthleteLastName{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("AthleteFirstName")]
    public string AthleteFirstName{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Number")]
    public string Number{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("IsPresent")]
    public string IsPresent{ get; set; }
}
```

And then deserialize it like below:

```
List<VisitingTeamFootballRbStats> visitingTeams = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<VisitingTeamFootballRbStats>>(jsonString["VisitingTeamFootballRbStats"].ToString());
```

So once you get the list, you can easily get the athletes details as below:

```
visitingTeams.ElementAt(0).AthleteLastName;
```

Or you can use linq.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because your json object is not a dictionary,it's a custom object 
here how it's  look a serialized dict

```
{"team1":[{"AthleteLastName":"v2",
"AthleteFirstName":"v1",
"Number":2,
"IsPresent":false}]}
```

Here a fully working  example

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           var team=  "{" +
                       "    \"InputKoffRetStats\":true,\"InputPenaltyStats\":false," +
                       "    \"VisitingTeamFootballRbStats\":" +
                       "         [{" +
                       "             \"AthleteLastName\":\"John\"," +
                       "             \"AthleteFirstName\":\"Smith\",\"Number\":9,\"IsPresent\":true" +
                       "         }," +
                       "         {" +
                       "             \"AthleteLastName\":\"Justin\"," +
                       "             \"AthleteFirstName\":\"Brooks\",\"Number\":10,\"IsPresent\":false" +
                       "         }]" +
                       "}";





            var desTeam = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Team>(team);  
            Console.WriteLine(desTeam.VisitingTeamFootballRbStats[0].AthleteFirstName);



        }
    }

    public class Team{
        public bool InputKoffRetStats { get; set; }
        public bool InputPenaltyStats { get; set; }
        public  List<AthleteInfo> VisitingTeamFootballRbStats { get; set; }

    }

    public class AthleteInfo
    {
        public string AthleteLastName { get; set; }
        public string AthleteFirstName { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public bool IsPresent { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

if you  are using  webapi/wcf you can  ask  for the data contract  otherwise you  can use dynamic object for this

**Note**
by using dynamic object you loose the  supports  of intellisense

***Code***

```
//same json string  

 dynamic desDynTeam = JObject.Parse(team);     
             Console.WriteLine(desDynTeam.VisitingTeamFootballRbStats[0].AthleteLastName);
```

Comment: I should have mentionned that the jsonText I gave was just a short part of the whole text. The whole json is over 1000 lines long. Your classes work fine in the example, but won't work with the whole text. Is there any way to create a generic class ?

Comment: yes you can  use the  dynamic  object but you loose the intellisense support see my update

Answer (score 1):

The VisitingTeamFootballRbStats array gets pretty long or there are other fields in the outer in the JSON. If the JSON is known and not going to change, I would still go with adding proper classes to my .NET project and deserialize into that.

Answer (score 0):

`dict["VisitingTeamFootballRbStats"][0]` gets you the whole `Athlete` object.

To access name use `.AthleteFirstName`

Like so:

```
dict["VisitingTeamFootballRbStats"][0].AthleteFirstName
```

Comment: I get an error while trying to do so: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [dynamics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) in .NET?  Here is a simple console app using [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) that shows how you can access those properties on your JSON object:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    dynamic dObject = JObject.Parse(json);

    Console.WriteLine(dObject.VisitingTeamFootballRbStats[0].AthleteLastName); 
    //Prints "John"

    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static string json = @"
    {
        'InputKoffRetStats':true,'InputPenaltyStats':false,
        'VisitingTeamFootballRbStats':
        [{
            'AthleteLastName':'John',
            'AthleteFirstName':'Smith','Number':9,'IsPresent':true
        },
        {
            'AthleteLastName':'Justin',
            'AthleteFirstName':'Brooks','Number':10,'IsPresent':false
        }]
    }
    ";
```